# Need help finding xygraph dependency in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, nebula

I am trying to use the XYGraph in the Nebula visualization tool from eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/visualization/visualization.php) to create charts and graphs in my Java application, I am using Maven to manage my dependencies as I will be building the project on a remote machine which can then pull the dependencies as described in the Maven POM. My problem is, I can't find the dependency for Nebula ANYWHERE! I tried looking for the repo in repo.eclipse.org, the Maven central repo, even mvnrepository.com.The Nebula website contains a link to the download the P2 repo but no information about an m2 repo. I can't find the dependency anywhere and hence can't use it unless I manually import all the jars. Is there anyone who knows where I can find the XYGraph library dependency. I tried using all the repositories mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Services/Nexus but still no luck. Is there any other way I can get that dependency into my project using Maven. The way I'm trying out different repositories is by changing the content in the following xml tags:

```
    <repository>
        <id>repo.eclipse.org</id>
        <name>Eclipse Nebula Plugin</name>
        <url> https://repo.eclipse.org</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.nebula</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where did you get those coordinates from??
Also, try searching by class name in here 
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22my.class%22

Comment: Inside the jar there is a pom.xml file for the xygraph, I took the coordinates from there, the repo url I was trying different links from the Eclipse Wiki link I posted above.

Comment: i see. it must be a proprietary repo. Try the class search i mentioned. maybe it has been made public under a different GAV

Comment: The class search doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to grab the whole Nebula visualization package. There's an example POM file [here](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula/blob/master/widgets/visualization/org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.exampleview/pom.xml), but I haven't tested it.

If that fails, you can download the JAR and [install it in your local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project).